# Xcode Linker error: can't allocate region

Tags: xcode4, linker

I want to run an app on the iPad2 but at linking I got this error:

```
collect2: ld terminated with signal 6 [Abort trap]
ld(69392) malloc: *** mmap(size=16777216) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
```

I dont know whats the reason for this error. It look like allocating 16777216 bytes (16MB) and the iPad2 should handle that!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you got the error at linking, and that it didn't successfully link, install and begin to run, THEN get the error?

The error you have is because malloc can't allocate another 16M block, and THAT is almost certainly because you have either crazy memory fragmentation (possible, but not as common) or a memory leak (very common!)

It would be odd to see this coming form the linker/XCode tools (unless you're running betaware, in which case who knows?!)  It's more likely in your app.

Comment: I had a similar problem but received no low memory notification. Do you have an idea why?